# Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/w

Tags: zend-framework

my index file is this

```
<?php
ini_set( "short_open_tag", 1 );
ini_set( "display_errors", 1 );
// Define path to application directory

defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));
/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

// Let 'er rip
$application->bootstrap()->run();
```

when i run that

Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/Giftercity_backup/index.php on line 18 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' (include_path=':.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/Giftercity_backup/index.php on line 18

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 6):

For Ubuntu.
If you install `ZendFramework` package. i.e. `sudo apt-get install zend-framework`
It will put zend library files in `/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/ folder`
you have to just copy and paste that `Zend/ folder into /user/share/php/`
Run the following command in terminal.

```
cd /usr/share/php
sudo cp -R libzend-framework-php/Zend/ Zend
```

Comment: I would create a symlink instead but you answer is essentially what I do

Comment: @Angel.King.47 yes you can do that also.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 1):

Put your index file in "public" directory.

Or if you want or cannot include files from parent directory you need to change this line:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
  realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
  get_include_path(),
)));
```

To

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
  realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/library'), // Here we have change
  get_include_path(),
)));
```

Of course I assume that you have already putted your Zend Files into library/Zend

You also need to remember to put .htaccess file with "deny from all" to your application, library, and any other directory you don't want users to get access to.

Btw.
This method of including library is quite old and not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If your `index.php` file is located in `/var/www/Giftercity_backup/index.php` (according to the error output) then according to your code the `library` location should be in `/var/www/library` and `application` in `/var/www/application` which sounds wrong.

`index.php` should be in a public folder such as `/var/www/Giftercity_backup/public`, `/var/www/Giftercity_backup/htdocs` or similar and your VirtualHost DocumentRoot should point to that folder.

Additionally, your `set_include_path` didn't register `library`  (include_path=':.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear').

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507